# Inspecting end of file during reading the file by ReadFile() function

Tags: c++, c, winapi

How can I inspect end of file in next code. I try to write function that can read wchar_t symbols one by one while some define earlier symbol be read, but if EOF be read function must stop.

```
wchar_t wchr[1];    
BOOL b = TRUE;

do
{
    b = ReadFile(hReadFile, wchr, sizeof(wchar_t), &dw, NULL);
    if(!b)break;         //it doesn't work
    tempGetLine[size] = wchr[0];
    size++;
}while(wchr[0] != endSymbol);
```

Comment: `dw` will be zero on EOF. It's all in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to check if `ReadFile` is at the end of the file is to check how many bytes it has read vs how many you requested. That is:

```
if(!b)break;
```

should read:

```
if(dw != sizeof(wchar_t)) break;
```